# How do I set the ground image and sky image in unity (3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I set the ground image and sky image in unity (3D)? I have already downloaded files from the assest store for both. The ground is independent of the sky. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

```
Edit -> Render Settings -> Skybox Material
```

Then just add a `Skybox Material`.

[image]

For the ground watch this video about terrain sculpting.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqv-eBug02g

Comment: Depends what your ground is. Is it a terrain?

Comment: I have four things included in my ground folder. One of them is a texture (it looks like a globe)

Comment: @JonahStarling watch the video I just posted. That should teach you about terrains.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I watched the videos and they helped out some.